# How to select rows based on the entry value of the first column?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

```
Data={{0,5678},{0,5654},{1,87675},{2,243},{2,257},{1,9790},{0,7688},{1,97779},{0,6858}}
```

Given a data set similar to the above, how can I select rows where the first column entry is a number that I specify, and the following row is a row is where the first column entry is another number that I specify, and only alternating first column entries, for instance,

Choose 0
Choose 1

I'd like the output to be,

```
{{0,5678},{1,87675},{0,7688},{1,97779}}
```

Or if I do

Choose 1
Choose 2

I'd like the output to be,

```
{{1,87675},{2,243},}
```

etc.

So far, I have

```
Cases[Data,{n_,_}/;n>=1]
```

This doesn't quite do it, but it's a start. Thanks!

Comment: Something like `SplitBy[Select[Data, MatchQ[{0 | 1, _}]], First][[All, 1]]`?

Answer (score 5):

#### [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html)

```
Join @@ SequenceCases[data, {{0, _}, {1, _}}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}
> ```

```
Join @@ SequenceCases[data, {{1, _}, {2, _}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}
> ```

#### [`SequencePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) + [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
Join @@ (data[[#]] & /@ SequencePosition[data[[All, 1]], {0, 1}])
```

> ```
>  {{0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}
> ```

```
Join @@ (data[[#]] & /@ SequencePosition[data[[All, 1]], {1, 2}])
```

> ```
>  {{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}
> ```

#### [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) + [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

```
Join @@ Select[Length @ # >= 2 &] @ Split[data, #[[1]] == 0 && #2[[1]] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> {{0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}
> ```

```
Join @@ Select[Length @ # >= 2 &]@ Split[data, #[[1]] == 1 && #2[[1]] == 2 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}
> ```

#### [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) + [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

```
Join @@ Select[#[[All, 1]] == {0, 1} &] @ Partition[data, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}
> ```

```
Join @@ Select[#[[All, 1]] == {1, 2} &] @ Partition[data, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}
> ```

#### [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html)

```
BlockMap[If[#[[All, 1]] == {0, 1}, Sequence @@ #, Nothing] &, data, 2, 1]
```

> ```
>  {{0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}
> ```

```
BlockMap[If[#[[All, 1]] == {1, 2}, Sequence @@ #, Nothing] &, data, 2, 1]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{0, 5678}, {0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {2, 243}, {2, 257}, 
  {1, 9790}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}, {0, 6858}};

f = Catenate @ Partition[First /@ SplitBy[Cases[list, {#, _}], First], 2] &;

f[0 | 1]
```

{{0, 5678}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}

```
f[1 | 2]
```

{{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0, 5678}, {0, 5654}, {1, 87675},
       {2, 243}, {2, 257}, {1, 9790}, 
       {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}, {0, 6858}};
```

---

Using `SequencePosition` and `Extract`:

```
f = Extract[#1, List /@ Union @@ SequencePosition[#1, {{#2, _}, {#3, _}}]] &;

f[data, 0, 1]
```

> {{0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}

```
f[data, 1, 2]
```

> {{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}

Or using `Partition` and `Pick`:

```
f[l_, {m_, n_}] := 
Join @@ Pick[#, #[[1, 1]] == m && #[[2, 1]] == n & /@ #] &@Partition[l, 2, 1]

f[data, {0, 1}]
```

> {{0, 5654}, {1, 87675}, {0, 7688}, {1, 97779}}

```
f[data, {1, 2}]
```

> {{1, 87675}, {2, 243}}